# exercise on convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

How can I prove that a sequence in a metric space converges to an element iff every sub-sequence has a sub-sub-sequence convergent to that element.
Thank for the help!!

Comment: I think "succession" should be "sequence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $x_n$ does not converge to $L,$ then for some $\epsilon>0,$ there is no $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $d(x_n,L) <\epsilon.$ Argue that this implies there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $d(x_{n_k},L) \ge\epsilon$ for all $k.$